# Can the Hilbert space of a system depend on time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, time

It's postulated that the state of a quantum mechanical system is represented by a ray in a Hilbert space. I'm aware that the ray may depend on time, but can the Hilbert space itself depend on time? Does the answer depend on whether or not the potential energy is time-dependent?
I'm only asking within the context of nonrelativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: The Hilbert space is the container in which you describe your system. If the Hilbert space changes it means that your system changes. But this is totally ok. If your potential depends on time but still depends on a single variable $x$ your system still describe one particle. But you could make it such that at a given time the potential starts depending on two variables. This can describe the situation where at some given time you injected a particle in the system (describing now two particles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You may *choose* a *representation* of the Hilbert space that is time-dependent, but the Hilbert space itself is a vector space that contains all possible states of the system, and it does not depend on time (that is, on the evolution of the state of the system within this space).

Comment: "but the Hilbert space itself contains is a vector space". Please fix that grammar for clarity

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy It's usually a good idea to try to be polite to people who are answering your questions.

Comment: @Javier How would you have worded my request more politely?

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy Maybe something along the lines of "Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by 'the Hilbert space itself contains is a vector space'. Would you mind rewording it?". Questions are usually more polite than commands.

Comment: @yu-v Would you please confirm or deny that your answer holds when the potential energy of the system is time-dependent

Comment: sure. it doesn't matter if the Hamiltonian is time dependent or not. For **any** dynamic of the system (that is - for any time-evolution) the Hilbert space is fixed. The time evolution may be very complicated and involving different vectors from the Hilbert space, but the space itself is fixed. When we *solve* the problem it is sometimes useful to introduce a time-dependent *basis* of states in which we expand the Hilbert space, but this is just a (convenient) choice that we make, and it only concern the *representation* of the space. The space itself is time independent. Always.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rather think: if the Hilbert space changed, in what could it change to? Finite dimensional (complex) Hilbert spaces are characterized by a single number, its dimension. All Hilbert spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic to each other. The same essentially happens in infinite dimension (for separable Hilbert spaces).

Think now in finite dimensions. You can postulate $H=H(t)$. Such (time dependent) space is entirely characterized by its dimension $d(t)=\mathrm{dim} H$. This function is integer valued and can only change abruptly at some given times.

In principle you can think that this situation describes something like: at some given times particles enter or exit the system. To be precise you should use the Fock space to make this analogy rigorous, but it's still a meaningful prescription.

However in order to describe this situation you could simply consider a Hilbert space big enough to accommodate all your smaller spaces. Then the Hilbert space would be fixed in time but your wavefunction still has the ability to be supported in whichever subspace you want.

A similar situation happens in statistical mechanics. There you have the possibility to describe systems at a fixed number of particle (which theoretically can even depend on time), or you consider at once the space with all possible particle numbers. This latter is called Fock space.